# SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message could not be sent

Tags: php, email

I am presently trying to use phpmailer in sending mails to a gmail through smtp protocol but I don't understand even after googling it I got an error that the message could not be sent I am presently on my localhost and the error I got is

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed 
because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, 
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to 
respond. (10060)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message could not be sent.
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

and the php code I have written is

```
<?php
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;   
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                     
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     
$mail->Username = "rammanoj.potla1608@gmail.com";  
$mail->Password = "marjo741963"; 
$mail->port = 587;
$mail->From = "rammanoj.potla@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "rammanoj";
$mail->AddAddress("rammanojpotla1608@gmail.com", "ram");                

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                 

$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

thankyou

Comment: Dont you have to instantiate an object from the phpMailer class before attempting to use the object?

Comment: Have you checked that your php.ini has openssl enabled? `extension=php_openssl.dll`

Comment: can you brief it once I have even tried the answer to many questions  on thiis in stackoverflow but I could not find any solution

Comment: no I have not enabled it

Comment: Then DO SO. Cannot use TSL without it

Comment: I found thees things near it asp_tags=Off
display_startup_errors=On
track_errors=Off
y2k_compliance=On
allow_call_time_pass_reference=Off
safe_mode=Off
safe_mode_gid=Off
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars=PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars=LD_LIBRARY_PATH
error_log="C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log"
register_globals=Off
register_long_arrays=Off
magic_quotes_gpc=Off
magic_quotes_runtime=Off
magic_quotes_sybase=Off
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_ftp.dll

Comment: I dont understand where to enable it ? i cant find any option such enable_openssl

Comment: yes done it uncommented the line extension=php_openssl.dll

Comment: but then even it returns me the same error

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rammanoj/fc000e69d457a4fdf9ecfbd5d4b5cb2b-got this error